# How to get that realistic palm leaf shadow?

Tags: modeling, light

I want to have a shadow of a palm tree leaf on my product in Blender (cycles). Something like:

[image]

I want this to look realistic, is modelling the leaf the best way to go about this? Is there any other way?

Comment: you can model the leaf or you can use an image of leaf on a plane with alpha transparency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way is to download an image from google and use the image to cast a shadow.

To do this, write: "palm tree leaf alpha".  It is important to download one with a transparent or completely black background.
In Blender, you have to enable import images as planes addon:
-Open user preferences:
[image]

-Go to Addons and type in the search bar "image":
[image]

-Press Shift+A to add the image as a plane:
[image]

If the image has an Alpha channel everything is ready.
[image]

If the image has a black background you have to do some work on the material:
-Open the shading workspace:
[image]

-Just copy this setup:
[image]

-Put the plane in front of the light source. You are done.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! Very helpful!

Answer (score 6):

If you need only the shadow of the leaf you can place a [transparent clipart](http://clipart-library.com/clip-art/palm-leaf-transparent-20.htm) of a leaf in front of a light. The size/radius of the light source determines how soft or hard the shadow is cast. (Well, the shadow is not that dark as in your image but you get the idea.)

[image]

Comment: thank you! I knew there had to be an easier way than have to make the palm leaf myself! thanks a bunch!